# what is the origin of the proof via peaks?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, math-history

What is the history of the proof of the existence of a monotone subsequence via peaks as found for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264049) as well as in problem 6, page 4 [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=678095) (where they are called "giants" instead of "peaks")? Is it known who discovered it first?

Comment: why this proof in particular would be of special interest ? and after looking at parts of Euler's http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/introductiontoanalysisvol1.htm I'm not sure he was thinking to "series in general" and not only to power series, recurrent series, harmonic series, or other special cases.

Comment: @user1952009 I am not sure why you are looking at Euler (who is definitely one of my favorites).  The source I gave dates from Dec 23 2012 which is a lot later. I am looking for some intermediate sources :-)

Comment: @user1952009, do these historical papers give a proof via peaks in special cases of sequences but that would work in general (if those mathematicians were interested in generality)?

Comment: @user1952009, but did they prove it via peaks?

Comment: Cauchy did understand that proof : he studied convergence of sequences which implies studying how the peaks converge to the limit.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have a precise reference? Note that there are proofs of the result that don't involve analysis of peaks.