# Find a continuous onto map from $(0,1]$ to $(-1,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find a continuous onto map from $(0,1]$ to $(-1,1)$.

My attempt: Would it be $f(x) = x^2 \sin\frac{1}{1-x}$? Am I correct?

Comment: Your function is not defined at 1, so no.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ would be better...

Comment: @Surb So, $f(x)= \sin(1/x)$ is the required continuous, onto  function ?

Comment: @AndrewZhang Ok, do my function work for continuous onto map from $[0,1)$ to $(−1,1)$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @AndrewZhang I think yes.

Comment: Surb's answer doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

$(1-x)\sin(1/x)$ works.

However, such a function can't have a limit at $0.$

Proof: Since $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $1$, we can construct a sequence of values where it gets within $1/2^n$ of $1.$ Call this sequence $s_n.$ By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, since it is bounded, it has a convergent subsequence $t_n.$ Let the limit of $t_n$ be $l.$ If $l \in (0,1],$ then $f(l) = 1.$ This is a contradiction, since $1$ is not in the range of $f.$ Therefore, $l$ must be $0.$ Therefore, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1.$ By similar logic, we can get that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = -1.$ This is a contradiction, so no such function exists.

Comment: Proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264049/prove-that-every-bounded-sequence-in-bbbr-has-a-convergent-subsequence

Comment: How about $$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
(1-x)\sin \left( \frac{1}{1-x}  \right),  & \text{if $x \neq 1$} \\
0, & \text{if $x =1$ }
\end{cases}$$

Comment: That is discontinuous.

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} (1-x)\sin \left( \frac{1}{1-x}\right)=0=f(1)$$

and 

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} (1-x) \sin \left( \frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\sin 1=f(0)$$

and

$f$ is continuous for $0 \lt x \lt 1$.

Am I right?

Comment: You are right, although it does not cover the interval (-1,1).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Define $A_n=\left(\frac{n}{n+1},(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{n+1} \right)$

and join $A_i, A_{i+1}$ for $i=0, 1, 2, \cdots$ as shown.

We obtain a continuous onto function $ f: [0,1) \to (-1,1)$.

Define $g: (0,1] \to [0,1) $ by $g(x)=1-x$

The composite function $f \circ g$ is a continuous onto function from $(0,1]$ to $(-1,1) $

Comment: Yes, but this function doesn't have a value at 1.

Comment: $f(g(1))=f(0)=0$

Comment: Oops, I missed the g part. This solution works, so I'm upvoting it.