# Justification of the proof of the uncountability of R

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation

In the textbook of Understanding Analysis by Stephen abbott, the author introduces the following proof of the uncoutability of $\mathbb{R}$:

---

Assume that there does exist a $1–1$,
onto function $f : \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{R}$. This suggests is that it is possible to enumerate the elements of R. If we let $x_1 = f(1), \hspace{1mm} x_2 = f(2)$,  and so on, then
our assumption that $f$ is onto means that we can write 
\begin{equation} R = \{x_1,\hspace{1mm} x_2,\hspace{1mm} x_3, \hspace{1mm} x_4,\hspace{1mm}... \} \end{equation}
and be confident that every real number appears somewhere on the list. We
will now use the Nested Interval Property  to produce a real
number that is not there. Let $I_1$ be a closed interval that does not contain $x_1$. Next, let $I_2$ be a closed interval, contained in $I_1$, which does not contain $x_2$. The existence of such an $I_2$ is easy to verify. Certainly $I_1$ contains two smaller disjoint closed intervals, and $x_2$ can only be in one of these. In general, given an interval $I_n$, construct
$I_{n+1}$ to satisfy 
 
(i) $I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n$ 
(ii) $x_{n+1} \notin I_{n+1}$

We now consider the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$. If $x_{n_0}$ is some real number from the list above, then we have $x_{n_0} \notin I_{n_0}$ , and it follows that
$$ x_{n_0} \notin \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_n$$
Now, we are assuming that the list in above contains every real number, and this leads to the conclusion that
$$\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_n = \emptyset$$
However, the Nested Interval Property (NIP) asserts that $ \hspace{0.2mm} \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_n \not = \emptyset$. By NIP, there is at least one $ x \in \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_n$ that, consequently, cannot be on the list. This contradiction means that such an enumeration of $\mathbb{R}$ is impossible,
and we conclude that $\mathbb{R}$ is an $\textit{uncountable}$ set.

---

The point I'm not understanding is how to justify that the nested intervals he makes won't be empty at infinity. I could prove by induction that for every n $\in \mathbb{N}$ I can construct $I_n$, such that $I_n$ is not empty and $x_n \notin I_n$, but I can't prove, using the assumption that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, this interval construction method won't eventually produce empty sets at infinity. So, can somebody present a rigorous proof that it won't?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141452/discussion-on-question-by-hesham-abdelgawad-justification-of-the-proof-of-the-un).

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

Let $s_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that each $I_n$ contains $s_n.$ By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, since $s_n$ is bounded (inside $I_1$), it has a convergent subsequence. Let this subsequence be $t_n$ and let its limit be $l.$ Assume that some interval ($I_k$) doesn't contain $l.$ Let the least distance from a point in $I_k$ to $l$ be $\varepsilon.$ By the definition of convergence, there are numbers $t_n$ within $\varepsilon/2$ of $l.$ Let the least-indexed such $t_n$ with index in $s$ at least $k$ be $s_r.$ Since $r \geq k,$ $I_r \subseteq I_k.$ However, $I_r$ must contain $s_r.$ This is a contradiction. Therefore, every such interval must contain $l.$ Thus proved.

Comment: Proof of Bolzano-Weirstrass: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264049/prove-that-every-bounded-sequence-in-bbbr-has-a-convergent-subsequence

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but unfortunately, I haven't reached the chapter about sequences yet. but, it turned that what i had a problem with is how the NIP gives a conclusion about the infinite intersection $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}I_n$ when I only proved the existence of such nested intervals for every finite natural number, not for the infinite case. So, if you can help me with that, it will be very appreciable.

Comment: @HeshamAbdelgawad You proved the existence for every finite natural number. It’s basically the same as having a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$, the index of every term is a finite number, but this is an infinite sequence. NIP is a statement about the limit of the intersection of the first $n$ nested intervals as $n\to\infty$, analogous to how $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$.

Comment: @Divide1918 By the same logic, I can say that since $$\bigcap_{i = 0}^{n} [i, \infty) \neq \emptyset$$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so it must be true for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$

Comment: @HeshamAbdelgawad By **what** logic? You **cannot** simply insert “by the same logic” before a random phrase and call that a sensible argument against my point. Let me spell it out for you. Is there a term $a_{\infty}$ in the infinite sequence $(a_n)$? No, there isn’t. “Infinite sequence” means a sequence $(a_n)$ such that, given any positive integer $N$, there is a term $a_N$ in that sequence. But $\infty$ is **NOT** a positive integer. In fact, $a_n$ may very well have no limit at all as $n\to\infty$. On what planet are your and my assertions “by the same logic”?